# Click image to change it, with hover effect HTML

Tags: image, onclick, hover, onmouseout

When I click my image, it changes (i removed onmouseover to test), but when i mouseout it reverts. How do I make it so my image has a rollover effect and also stays as the new image once clicked?

```
<img src="images/Character/NotSelected_Mage.png" alt="image"
onclick="this.src='images/Character/Selected_Mage.png'"/
onmouseover="this.src='images/Character/Selected_Mage.png';"
onmouseout="this.src='images/Character/NotSelected_Mage.png';">
```

I'm a beginner so i'm only using html, if I have to use CSS or javascript or jquery (would that mean users would have to install javascript to view my website?) do I have to place anything in my code to tell it that i'm suddenly using something other than html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line:

`onclick="this.src='images/Character/Selected_Mage.png'"`

To:

`onclick="this.src='images/Character/Selected_Mage.png'; this.onmouseover = false; this.onmouseout = false;"`

Answer (score 0):

current browsers, by default, should run the html and javascript just fine, no need to'install anything.  No need to 'tell' users what your using / running.